# unusual callback calling

Tags: android, flash, air

I have such a problem: on device with Android OS, I am executing action script code. And I have a method, which must to send some data to sever. But!!! Even if I stop my application before sending some data to server - it still somehow sends that data. I don't understand how it can be?? Anyone faced with this problem? Please help me. Thanks.

```
public class VerifyCommand extends SimpleCommand
    {


        override public function execute(notification:INotification):void 
        {       
            //here is the place, where I put breakpoint and stop the program
            trace("here is the place, where I put breakpoint and stop the program");
            verify();
        }

        private function verify():void
        {
            var tempError:Error = new Error();
            var stackTrace:String = tempError.getStackTrace();
            trace(stackTrace);

            var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            request.url = "http://www.somesite.com";

            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            request.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
            request.data = variables;
            request.useCache = false;
            request.cacheResponse = false;

            var call_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            call_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            call_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onVerificationResult); 
            call_loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onVerificationError);
            call_loader.load(request);
        }

        private function onVerificationResult(event:Event):void 
        {
            trace("all ok");
        }

        private function onVerificationError( event:Event):void 
        {       
            trace("all failed");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a debugger fault , it doesn't stop exactly where I think it should.